# How to use delete() method in Google App Engine Python's request handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In GAE Python, I could use

```
class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        pass #Do Something...
    def post(self):
        pass #Do Something...
```

To handle GET and POST request. But how can I handle DELETE and PUT? I see delete() and put() in API documentation, but I don't know how to write a form to simulate DELETE and PUT.

I know in Rails, I can use post method with a hidden field in form to simulate the requests like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
```

and Rails handles the dirty works automatically.

Is there any similar way to do it in GAE python?

I searched this in Google, but no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the request method which accepts all the methods like get,post,delete and put.
Then you can check it for the request type accordingly.

Check this:

http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/gdata.urlfetch.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
 <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
 <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form> 

def post(self):
    method= self.request.get("_method")
    if method == 'put':
       #call put() function as required
```

you can go through this as well for the put specification.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass.html#RequestHandler_put

Comment: Thanks, this may be another solution to handle HTTP requests other than GET and POST. But I still don't know how to use the delete() method which is provided by App Engine. You know, the delete() method should exist for some reason, or maybe app engine has already have a solution to simulate DELETE request. But I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

The HTML specification doesn't allow a form to use the DELETE method, and you probably can't get a browser to send an HTTP DELETE request with a form.  The delete() method of a RequestHandler subclass would generally be used for a RESTful web application with a client that knows how to send DELETE requests, rather than using ordinary HTML forms.  (For a browser-based client, you can send DELETE requests in javascript using XMLHttpRequest.)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this simulation yourself of course, In pseudo code (I'm not familiar with GAE specifics):

```
def post(self):
    if request.get('_method', '') == 'delete':
        return self.post()
```

If you want to truely test PUT and DELETE you will have to find a way to actually use these methods in stead of simulating them. You can use curl for this, for example, i.e.

```
$ curl -X DELETE url
$ curl -T file url # for PUT
```

See the curl documentation / manpage for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This may be one of the ways to deal with HTTP DELETE request. But I was wondering, how can I really use the delete() method which is provided by Google App Engine API.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a new RequestHandler subclass :

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class RESTfulHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self, *args):
    method = self.request.get('_method')

    if method == "put":
      self.put(*args)
    elif method == "delete":
      self.delete(*args)
    else:
      self.error(405) # Method not allowed
```

Then your handler will inherit from it :

```
class MyHandler(RESTfulHandler):
  def get(self):
    ...
  def delete(self):
    ...
  def put(self):
    ...
  def post(self):
    ...
```

Here is another example using the X-HTTP-Method-Override header used by most JavaScript libraries : 
http://github.com/sork/webapp-handlers/blob/master/restful.py

Comment: what about actual post requests? shouldn't you call self.post(*args) instead of self.error() in case the child implements post()?